# Change legend labels in ggpubr

Tags: r, ggpubr

Is there a way to customize the labels in a legend when utilizing ggboxplot? 
I have a barplot with a legend in which the labels are taken from the data frame columns. I would like to change these labels without having to change the label of the column. Something akin to`scale_fill_discrete(labels=c(......)` in ggplot.

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked @Nicolás Velásquez answer a bit. You can also use

```
scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("First", "Second"))
```

This also works for `gghistogram`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Certainly. Ggplot2's scale_x_discrete() will do the trick.

```
ggBoxplot(as.data.frame(DFW2), y = 'shares', x = 'Polaridad') +
          scale_x_discrete(labels = c("First", "Second"))
```

ggboxplot() is but a wrapper around ggplot2's ggplot() and geom_box() functions, so all instructions for layers after ggplot() will work.